# Advantages of Scala's Lightweight Syntax?

Tags: scala, syntax, expression

Scala claims that it has lightweight syntax:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html

Scala claims that such syntax, especially the functional programming part, can make code more succinct.

Is this just a syntax simplification? Also, besides of more succinct code, is there any other pragmatic benefit can such "succinct syntax" bring to programmers?

Comment: I think this one is to *broad* and *opinion based* for this site (maybe try **Programmers**?) - but *less* code usually is easier to read, remember, maintain, ... ;)

Comment: consider `val x = List(42)` vs `val x: List[Int] = List[Int](42)`

Answer (score 0):

Advantages of Lightweight Syntax for me:

- A lightweight syntax helps with learning programming. It reduces the barrier to entry as a heavy syntax has lots of edge cases in its grammar which adds complexity to the learning process.
- A lightweight syntax coupled with extension mechanisms and lots of freedom to name functions/methods makes designing a DSL much more simple as less possible symbols will be reserved.
- A lightweight syntax is easier for humans to read and for computers to parse, which does help with quality of code and the compile/debug process.
- A complex syntax suggests edge cases in the semantics of the language.